# Permission on specific item

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, permissions

I am trying to give permission to an item in list but the user get the message that he dose not have permission.

**Scenario:**

User permission:

Site- none
list - none
item - Edit

Then I Sent direct link to the item itself and still - the user get message "no permission"

Answer (score 4):

In order to edit an item through the default SharePoint edit form, the user will need at least View Only permissions on the list.  Since editform belongs to the list, and the user cannot view the list, the user cannot edit the item.

Either rethink the security model for the list, or create a custom page that acts as an edit form, using JSOM, REST, or SPServices to update the list item.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the version of SharePoint 2013 so here is the guidance on item-level permission http://office.microsoft.com/en-sg/sharepoint-help/edit-permissions-for-a-list-library-or-individual-item-HA102833689.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is not solved I gave permissions of participating on the item only so the user dose not have permissions on the list or the site.
The user get message "you don't have permission on list"

Comment: Ensure that the user has permissions on the list, as well as the list item, if inheritance is broken.